# DexClassLoader and GooglePlay Policy

Tags: java, android, google-play, classloader, dex

There is an application that downloads the code from the assets folder (secure). I would like to know how Google Play Market will react to the application with the packed code in the assets folder? Or advise how and where to extract the code, which can later be run, and not violate the policies of Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/intl/en-US/about/developer-content-policy-print/) state that applications must not download unrestricted executable code from any source other than Google Play and introduce security vulnerabilities.

Hence packing your .dex files inside published APK (e.g. in assets) and extracting them into the application's private directory should be permitted.